# Is Win 10 Microsoft Advertising SDK compatible with Win 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-10

Microsoft very recently released the "Microsoft Advertising SDK" for Windows 10, which converges the previous SDKs (Phone n Desktop) into one SDK. I'm wondering if the new one is still compatible with Windows 8.1 (will it still work?).

As far as I've understood the API is nearly identical, but I still can't find whether or not it will work.

According to the documentation its **highly recommended** that one uninstall both previous Ad SDKs before installing the new one.

I would rather avoid the whole process of uninstalling, installing, reinstalling etc. therefore I'm asking here.

Thank you!

PS: *Would be nice if someone could create the tag **microsoft-advertising-sdk***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted Microsoft about this and confirmed that the Advertising SDK for Windows 10 isn't compatible with Windows 8.1.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft advertising SDK for Windows 10 is not compatible with Windows 8.1. I'm using DesktopAd SDK, it supports both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. If you are considering change your ad network, my answer may be helpful.:)

Answer (score 0):

That is not true, DesktopAd does not work for Windows 10. I decided to give it a shot, and migrated demo project from GitHub to Windows 10. Banner throws "The method or operation is not implemented." exception on load with following stacktrace:

```
 at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.InvokeScript(String scriptName, String[] arguments)
 at DesktopAd.Banner.EvalScript(String[] script)
 at DesktopAd.Banner.ContentWebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
```

It looks like WebView.InvokeScript is not supported for UWP.

Don't waste your time trying to make it work for Windows 10.

BTW, sample quality is terrible, and web site is not displayed properly on Chrome. Not sure if this is a good ads provider.

I also tried InMobi and LeadBolt for Windows 8 before, and they are pretty useless as well. So we stuck with PubCenter and AdDuplex.

Sorry, don't have enough points to comment on posts yet.

Comment: This should have been left as a comment to Moira Yao's answer, not as an answer to my question.